# jQuery.Deferred exception: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting '_renderItem')

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been using the following code to render the autocomplete results:

```
$('#'+id_input).data("ui-autocomplete")._renderItem = function(ul, item){
            let conteudo="";

            conteudo += "<div class='autocomplete__comparador' >"+
                            "<div style='display:inline-block;vertical-align:top;'>" +
                                "<div class='autocomplete_nome_fundo'><span style='font-size:14px;'>" + item.ticker + '</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;' + item.nome + "</div>"+
                            "</div>"+
                        "</div>";

            return $("<li class=''></li>")
            .data("item.autocomplete", item)
            .append(conteudo)
            .appendTo(ul)
        };
```

However, I'm getting the following code error:

```
jquery-3.6.0.js:4050 jQuery.Deferred exception: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting '_renderItem') TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting '_renderItem')
```

Does anyone know how to solve this? I'm using jquery-3.6.0 and jquery-ui 1.13.2

Comment: `.data()` return `undefined` if the named data item isn't found.

Comment: Try logging `$('#'+id_input).data("ui-autocomplete")` it seems to be undefined.

Comment: What is `id_input`?  I made a guess of "brown bear" but he said no dice.

Comment: This is not a good way to assign the `render_item` function. Please see: https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#custom-data

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('#'+id_input).data("ui-autocomplete")._renderItem = function(ul, item){
        let conteudo="";

        conteudo += "<div class='autocomplete__comparador' >"+
                        "<div style='display:inline-block;vertical-align:top;'>" +
                            "<div class='autocomplete_nome_fundo'><span style='font-size:14px;'>" + item.ticker + '</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;' + item.nome + "</div>"+
                        "</div>"+
                    "</div>";
        item.label = conteudo;
        return $("<li class=''></li>")
        .data("item.autocomplete", item)
        .append(item.label)
        .appendTo(ul);
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

Turned out that I was passing the wrong ID LOL, however, as specified by Twisty, this is not the best way to assign the render_item function. The best way is the following:

```
autocomplete( "instance" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
            let conteudo="";

            conteudo += "<a><span class=\"left\">" + item.ticker + "</span> <span class=\"right\">" + item.nome + "</span></a>";
            return $("<li class=''></li>")
              .append(conteudo)
              .appendTo(ul);
          };
```